# React Native Linking URL returns null during iOS app launch

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, deep-linking

I am unable to handle Linking url in iOS app when app launches. I am getting url null at the time of iOS app launch. Working properly when app is already running. Below is the code I am using for the same. I added `getInitialURL()` and `addEventListner()` methods as it is mentioned in the [online source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking) to that `getInitialURL()` works during app launch. Please help solving the issue. I use the following versions:

> "react": "16.8.3",
> "react-native": "0.59.8",

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then((event) => {
    if (event) {
        Logger.log("Url from getInitialUrl" + event)
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.warn('An error occurred', err);
});

Linking.addEventListener('url', (event) => {
     console.log("Add Event Listener" + event)
});
```

I have followed [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking) for the iOS linking integration.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem and found that `Linking.getInitialURL()` was returning null when react native debugging was enabled. When I stopped the debugging then it was giving the correct url. You can also try stopping the debugger and using some other way to check url like using javascript's `alert()` method or something like that. Hope it'll help :)